# General topological proof of the Cantor Intersection Theorem

Tags: general-topology

The proof of the Cantor Intersection Theorem (from Wikipedia, stated in the context of a general topological space) is the following.

> Assume by contradiction that there is a nested sequence of compact sets $(C_\alpha)_{\alpha < \kappa}$, where $C_\alpha \subseteq C_\beta$ for $\beta \leq \alpha$, such that $\bigcap_{\alpha < \kappa} C_\alpha = \emptyset$. For each $\alpha < \kappa$ define $U_\alpha = C_0 \setminus C_\alpha$. Then, since $\bigcup_{\alpha < \kappa} U_\alpha = C_0 \setminus \bigcap_{\alpha < \kappa} C_\alpha$ and $\bigcap_{\alpha < \kappa} C_\alpha = \emptyset$, we have that $\bigcup_{\alpha < \kappa} U_\alpha = C_0$. Since $C_0 \subseteq S$ is compact and $(U_\alpha)_{\alpha < \kappa}$ is an open cover of it, we have  $\kappa_0 \subseteq \kappa$, for $\kappa_0$ finite, such that $\bigcup_{\alpha < \kappa_0} U_\alpha = C_0$. **Let $U_\gamma$ be the largest set of this subcover.** Then $C_0 \subseteq U_\gamma$, but $C_\gamma = C_0 \setminus U_\gamma = \emptyset$, which is a contradiction.

Emphasis mine. I fail to see how $C_0 \subseteq U_\gamma = C_0 \setminus C_\gamma$, since $C_\gamma \neq \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that since $C_\alpha\subseteq C_\beta$ for $\beta\leq \alpha$ it follows also that $U_\alpha\supseteq U_\beta$ for $\beta\leq \alpha$, i.e. the sets $U_\alpha$ are increasing in $\alpha$.

Now since $\kappa_0$ is finite, it follows that $\bigcup_{\alpha<\kappa_0}U_\alpha=U_\gamma$, where $\gamma=\max\{\alpha\colon\alpha<\kappa_0\}$. This implies that $U_\gamma=C_0$, and therefore $C_\gamma=\varnothing$, which contradicts our hypothesis that each of the nested sets $C_\gamma$ is non-empty.